# In OpenERP, how can I determine how stock from purchases are assigned to which manufacturing orders?

Tags: odoo

## Summary

In a scenario where I'm about to receive a shipment of raw materials that isn't large enough to fill all my outgoing shipments and production orders, how can I predict which outgoing shipments and production orders those raw materials will be assigned to?

## Details

I have a new test database upon which I did the following:

### Setup

1. Create a product to produce, make_to_stock, (say, 'Cabinet')
2. Create a product to buy, make_to_stock, (say, 'Wood')
3. Add a BOM to the Cabinet product containing a single BOM line, one 'Wood'
4. Add a supplier to the Cabinet
5. Add an orderpoint to keep the VA of Wood at zero (that is, never keep stock)

### Process

1. Create a procurement request for Cabinet
2. Run procurement
3. The procurement created an MO for cabinet, found the BOM, and created a few move lines for the Cabinet and Wood, and created a procurement for each product
4. Confirm procurement from MO for Wood, and watch it go into exception.

At this time, there are four stock moves in the system:

```
1. Cabinet Stock->Stock, from initial procurement, in state 'confirmed' (waiting on #2)
2. Cabinet Production->Stock, from MO, in state 'waiting' (waiting on #3)
3. Wood Stock->Production, to be consumed by MO, in state 'waiting' (waiting on #4)
4. Wood Stock->Stock, procurement reservation from MO input, in state 'exception' (no stock found)
```

Now, to continue:

1. Run scheduler. This creates a new procurement for Wood, because the VA < 0, based on the orderpoint we defined. It also confirms and runs that procurement, which creates a new purchase order for Wood and sets up draft stock moves.
2. Confirm that PO, which will assign the stock moves.
3. It is at this point that we'd be waiting for the Wood to be delivered. Go to receive products, and confirm the stock move.

At this point, the four stock moves are in the same state, and there are two additional ones for Wood, one from Suppliers->Stock, and one from Stock->Stock. In the last step, we confirmed the move into Stock->Stock.

Currently we have 1 Wood in stock, and 1 Wood procurement in exception due to not enough stock.

My question is, how can I determine where this wood will be assigned in the future? If that is not possible (seems like it might not be), then after retrying the procurement and seeing it succeed, how can I tell where the stock move was initially assigned from?

To be clear as to why this is needed, we will have a delivery of several products, and we'd like to physically place them either in stock or directly in front of a machine that is going to need it. That is, we'd like to be able to trace the delivery stock moves directly though to it's assigned slot in a MO.

For additional referance, here's what the stock moves look like after that Wood procurement is retried:

```
#Initial Procurement
37787: 1.0 Base Cabinet (copy) [Stock -> Stock] (confirmed waiting for 37788) (procured from 16580)
#MO final product
37788: 1.0 Base Cabinet (copy) [Production -> Stock] (waiting waiting for 37789) (finished product of MO 7433)
#MO source product (has move history with 37790)
37789: 1.0 1/2ChinFPly1s (copy) [Stock -> Production] (assigned waiting for 37790) (to be consumed by 7433)
#Procurement for input, waiting for something in stock
37790: 1.0 1/2ChinFPly1s (copy) [Stock -> Stock] (done) (procured from 16581)

#------------------------------
#------------------------------

#Procurment from Orderpoint, putting something in stock (has move history with 37794)
37791: 1.0 1/2ChinFPly1s (copy) [Stock -> Stock] (done waiting for 37794) (procured from 16582)
37794: 1.0 1/2ChinFPly1s (copy) [Suppliers -> Stock] (done) (final move of PO line 3)
```

There does not seem to be any way to connect the first four moves with the last two.

Comment: You'll get more answers if you don't bury the lead. I added a summary at the top for you.

Comment: If you get the answer just select specific and close the workflow.

Answer (score 1):

in core openerp there is no feature that can tell you about the stock  from which order are assigned to what order. you have to implement or search on internet for the fifo lifo module that can help you . for ref : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DfoxZLxagXQ

Comment: Thanks, that did seem to be the case. I think FIFO / LIFO is a bit more than we need, so i've started to work around the issue by (more or less) re-implementing the scheduler's procurement retries just before and just after I approve a stock move into stock. Doing this lets me notice which procurement was able to accept the new stock and attach that information back to the order line. Of course, this only works one by one on a PO basis, so it's not an ideal solution.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the procurements that come earlier in the schedule will get first choice of any shipments you just received. You can override that by manually rerunning procurements before the MRP scheduler runs or by adjusting the `date_planned` field of procurements.

The next time the MRP scheduler runs after your shipment is received, it will go through all procurements that are in the exception state and try to restart them. In [the scheduler code](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~openerp/openobject-addons/6.1/view/head:/procurement/schedulers.py#L64), you can see that it processes them ordered by `date_planned`.

```
if not ids:
    ids = procurement_obj.search(cr, 
                                 uid, 
                                 [('state', '=', 'exception')], 
                                 order="date_planned")
for id in ids:
    wf_service.trg_validate(uid, 'procurement.order', id, 'button_restart', cr)
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I was initially going to do, but then if I query the list for the second orderline before the scheduler runs, then I will end up assigning everything to the first move. I ended up doing a variant on this, which was create a "receive these" button for the PO and running the procurement workflow myself, and testing if the procurement was successful. Then, if it was, I add that procurement to a new field on the OL so I can reference it later.